# Parse android: paging error

Tags: android, android-listview, parse-platform

Anybody seen this error when clicking on load more cell on a `Listview` using `ParseQueryAdapter`.

```
03-24 06:51:52.141    6168-6168/com.johamcruz.Balln E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
            at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
            at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
            at com.parse.ParseQueryAdapter$3.done(ParseQueryAdapter.java:384)
            at com.parse.FindCallback.internalDone(FindCallback.java:45)
            at com.parse.FindCallback.internalDone(FindCallback.java:31)
            at com.parse.Parse$6$1.run(Parse.java:940)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My code is below 
                `@Override
                public View getNextPageView(View v, ViewGroup parent){
                   loadNextPage();
                   return View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.next_page_item,   null);
               }`

Comment: Your index is out of bounds. You need to step through the code to figure out why. My guess is that your load more cell is triggering some code that corresponds to an actual Parse object.

Comment: please! show the parts of your code related with error!